# Avoiding race conditions using thread Id in Java (Spring)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition

I have a Spring Boot web application. One of the services has a method that generates a CSV file and saves it to the disk. Then this method passes the file location to another method which emails the CSV file and then deletes it from disk. In order to avoid concurrency issues, I decided to add the thread Id to the file name as below:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

    @Autowired
    private ReportRepository serviceRepository;

    public List<item> generateReport(Timestamp minTime, Timestamp maxTime) {
        // some code to retrieve items list.
        String reportTitle = "report-" + Long.toString(Thread.currentThread().getId()) + ".csv";
        CsvFileWriter report = new CsvFileWriter(reportTitle);
        File file = report.writeCsvFile(data);
        File[] attachments = { file };
        sendReportViaEmail("Please find monthly report attached.", attachments);
        return items;
    }

    private void sendReportViaEmail(String body, File[] attachments) {
        // This method sends CSV via email and then delete the 'attachments' from disk.
    }

}
```

So far it seems to be working. What I would like to know is whether this is a good way to avoid race conditions in my situation. More specifically,

1. If there are concurrent requests to the api resource using this service, is each request be handled by a separate thread with unique thread ids?
2. Is the `sendReportViaEmail()` always called within the same thread as the thread calling `generateReport()`?

Comment: `Long.toString` is obsolete. Just use `"report-" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do will work, since `Thread`'s ID is guarantied to be unique within JVM.

Using `currentTomeMilis` as suggested in a comment is *not* a good idea since this is not guarantied to be unique (it's possible that two threads call it at the same time and get exactly same value).

If you want to use built-in facility to do this, have a look at [`File.createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-). Be aware however that the implementation (in Oracle 1.7 at least) depends on random numbers and in a case when two threads access it at the same time *and* get the same random number (very unlikely but possible), the method will throw an `IOException`.

---

The other method will be called in the same thread, if you call it...well, from the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the `createTempFile()` resource. I'm not invoking any thread explicitly even within `sendReportViaEmail()`. Thank you for the confirmation.